# For which $x$ the inequality $ax+be^{x/2}>c$, where $a,b,c,x>0$ holds

Tags: calculus

For which $x$ the inequality  $ax+be^{\frac{x}{2}}>c$ where $a,b,c,x>0$ holds. Can someone help me for this. Thank you.

Comment: As written, this makes no sense. Are you looking for the possible $a,b,c >0$ such that the inequality holds for any $x>0$ or what?

Comment: possibility of $x$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I tried using the derivative but it seems that don't have minimum or maximum

Comment: I think Vjosa is asking: Given $a, b, c > 0$, for what values of $x$ does the inequality $ax+be^{x/2} > c$ hold?  As both answers have indicated, it is sure to be true for large enough $x$, but at what value of $x$ equality obtains, I'm not sure that one can determine that analytically in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $x=0$,
$ax+be^{x/2}>c$
becomes
$b > c$.
So this will be false
at $x = 0$
if $b \le c$.

This will certainly be true
for
$x > max(0, 2\ln(c/b))$.
So, there will always be solutions
for large enough $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain me, please, the last step. How did you get $x > \max (0, 2 \ln (c/b))$.

Comment: It should be $x > min(0, 2 \ln(c/b))$ maybe!!!

Comment: If c< b, $\ln(c/b) < 0$. I put in the max to get around this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (now that it's clear you want $x$):

If $b \le c$, solve  $ax + b e^{x/2} = c$ using the Lambert W function.
Thus you want

$$x > \dfrac{c}{a} - 2\; W\left(\dfrac{b e^{c/(2a)}}{2a}\right)$$